# not able to parse special character as '&' using gson java

Tags: java, gson

I am using gson library to de-serialize my json into my pojo object

and my test is getting failed - when one of the value contains a special character like '&'

how shall I get the required value as it is received.

Answer (score 5):

I got it solved my changing Builder setting as follows:

```
gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Comment: ... which is fine, it even is encouraged to post a question+answer on a topic not covered yet. But the question should contain more details. In the current state no one could give an answer since we don't know the code etc., an example and a detailed description of the problem is missing. So imo the answer is good, the question is not.

Comment: my intend is to share the knowledge and the problem which occured with - I tried searching for this - but cudnt easily find it - My friend ankit helped me out and I thought to share this as this might be helpful to many others. Did I do something wrong ?